# Why does chess tempo fail at random; what is the biggest free database online that is reliable

Tags: online-chess, database

Sometimes chess tempo works.  Sometimes it does not.  Seems random. Is there another database that is completely reliable that is as big as chess tempo?

I am looking for a DB that gives the moves with winning percentage or else percent results for  WDL for each move.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by chess tempo "failing" - what do you mean by fail in this context? Curious as I haven't noticed anything especially problematic about it.

Comment: Sometimes I get to this url   https://chesstempo.com/game-database.html    and it shows moves with usage and percents etc.  Sometimes I go there and it shows two blue lines one of which should expand to the page I want but has a minus sign indicating it can only close that view  and the other one has a plus so I can click for more info.  Why would one identical url come up with two different views.  I am guessing the code has something hidden and depending on that switch when you get to that page you get one of the two views.

Comment: @edwinaoliver I did not address that part of your question because it may not be chesstempo's issue at all. I have owned an IT company for 25 years now, and it would easily be something wrong with your computer, or simply the Internet being a problem at that moment. It would really need to be diagnosed by an expert to say it was there problem.

Comment: P.S. And I did not say this in my answer, but I believe that ChessBase is the largest of all the online databases with good tournament sources. There might be bigger databases that use their own online blitz/bullet games, but the quality is surely lower.

Answer (score 2):

This fits the bill perfectly, and ChessBase is incredibly reliable:

https://database.chessbase.com/

You will have to create a free account, and there are features that are premium, but for winning percentages, it has that for free. I am logged into this with a free account and you can see the percentages in the screenshot.

[image]

Here is what it looks like with my paid account (just the right portion of the screen changed, so I only took a screenshot of that).

[image]

Chessgames.com also has what you are looking for in terms of percentages here, but with much fewer games: https://www.chessgames.com/perl/explorer

Comment: The complete differences in the accounts can be seen here: https://account.chessbase.com/en/matrix

Comment: I primarily use free chessbase for this

Comment: @MichaelWest  don't really need to use any free sites. Chess.com gives Masters a free account, I buy ChessBase main database products enough (ChessBase 15/Mega 2020/Fat Fritz currently) that I get free keys for the premium site as part of that, and I like chess24's videos and tournament coverage, so I actually bought a three-year membership during the Black Friday sale (40% off the already discounted three-year price was only about $150, but it just went up).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.365chess.com/opening.php

is probably the best free database.

Chessgames.com is good but will often stop you from going too deep into lines if you don't have a membership. It does have some useful search features though.

Lichess.org has a database but it includes site games and doesn't have as many high level games as some other sites. Still it could be useful if you're not prepping for 3+ hour tourament games.